# Can't pick other partition than "Boot Camp" when installing Windows on OS X Lion Server

Tags: windows, macos, boot

My new Mac Mini Server is running OS X Lion Server 10.7.3.

I want to install Windows 7 as a dual boot. I start up Boot Camp and use an ISO image to create a USB boot disk. I don't seem to be able to use the DVD to install, so I use an ISO image on disk. I continue with the Boot Camp installation, with all three options on the main screen checked.

When I get to the part where I have to pick a partition on which to install, the only one I can select, and must format, is the partition labeled `BOOTCAMP`. But the Boot Camp support software for Windows is installed there.

I can continue with the Windows installation, and boot into Windows 7 with no problem. But since the Boot Camp drivers were wiped out, I cannot connect to the network, etc. I don't have a Boot Camp control panel either.

I did this once before on my other Mac Mini Server I have, running the same OSX Lion Server 10.7.3, and it worked without a problem. I'm writing this message on that copy of Windows. But this new install just will not work, after two days of trying. I *must* get this working. I'm stumped.

Comment: @PaulR No, it is fine here.

Answer (score 0):

i hope you already got this worked out.

**[easiest fix]** After installing windows, boot into windows, and "explore" your installation USB key, and look for the bootcamp installer there.

If you no longer have that specific USB installer, try the following:

1. re-run bootcamp assistant, only selecting the second option,
   "download latest windows support software from apple."
2. burn the support software to disc, or place on a USB key.
3. boot to windows.
4. install support software from media used in step 2
5. profit. =D

Boot Camp Assistant will not install the Boot Camp drivers to your Windows installation for you. It will only download the latest support software to your apple partition, and help you put it on some sort of removable media(CD/DVD/USB).

Boot Camp provides 3 Task options, the second of which is, "Download the latest windows support software from apple," If this second option is checked, you would be prompted to create a CD/DVD or to store the drivers on a USB key along-side the windows 7 installer.

best of luck. glhf.